# how to get data into LiveData<List<Model>> from DataSnapshot

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, mvvm, data-binding

I am attempting to load data from a Firebase DataSnapshot, but I don't receive any data when trying this:

```
override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("/users")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("UserRepository","databaseError ${databaseError.message}")
            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    value = dataSnapshot.children
                }
            }

        })
}
```

But with the code above I do not receive any data in `dataSnapshot`

Comment: please add some more info to your question ? what is happening/not happening and what are you expecting

Comment: Agreed, a stack trace if you have one is worth a lot of information, some additional explanations about where you're overriding this function from can be useful as well.

Comment: m new to kotlin, I am Trying to store data into MutableLiveData<List<Model>> from datasnapshot as hash map. but m getting casting error:-

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`DataSnapshot` has `getChildren()` which contains data snapshot instances, all you need to do is using a for loop in order to be able to access all `DataSnapshot` instances to get `YourModelClass` class by using `getValue()`.then add them into the model list

```
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

    YourModelClass modelObject = ds.getValue(YourModelClass.class);
    Log.d("TAG", modelObject.getMsg());
    modelList.add(modelObject)
}
```

Comment: Although this may be a correct answer. Three lines of code isn't very useful without an explanation of what and how it solves the original question. Please provide details to your answer.

Comment: @RyanNerd thanks for your comment, I just added my detail explanation.